# How might I convert a double to the nearest integer value?

Tags: c#, rounding

How do you convert a double into the nearest int?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `Math.round()`, possibly in conjunction with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`

eg:

```
Math.Round(1.2) ==> 1
Math.Round(1.5) ==> 2
Math.Round(2.5) ==> 2
Math.Round(2.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) ==> 3
```

Comment: Won't `Convert.ToInt32()` do the same thing, or does it simply strip everything after the decimal?

Comment: Does not actually produce an integer, but a double.

Comment: I think there is a contradiction (i.e. error) between lines 2 and 3 above, no?

Comment: @Ronnie - nope, that's by design. By default, Math.Round will round midpoint numbers (x + .5) to the nearest *even* number. If you want a different behaviour, you have to specify it via a flag. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx

Comment: If you need an integer use `Convert.ToInt16(NumberToConvert);`  The `16` can be replaced with `32` or `64`.

Comment: Does anyone else ever get tripped up by this default behavior ALL THE TIME??

Comment: Double is not Int.

Comment: Just simply *cast* the double to int like so `(int)Math.Round(value);`

Comment: Why is `Math.Round(1.5) ==> 2` and `Math.Round(2.5)` is also `==> 2`?

Answer (score 312):

```
double d = 1.234;
int i = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx)

Handles rounding like so:

> rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway
>   between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5
>   is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Comment: Much better that `Math.Round` as it returns an int as required.

Comment: @robert-koritnik. Not sure why that's "invalid". OP did not specify a preferred rounding rule, and "round .5 to nearest even" is the standard rule from way back. Always rounding up has unwanted statistical effects.

Comment: @Keith: I don't know but I've always been taught to round *x.5* up but I can see reasoning to do it up or down for statistics. Thanks for that. ***PS** It's clear to see I'm not in statistics, finance or accounting where this kind of rounding seems to be default*.

Comment: "Always rounding up has unwanted statistical effects" -- That's just plain false. Rounding .5 up rounds exactly half the numbers -- `[0,.5)` -- down and exactly half the numbers -- `[.5,1)` -- up. Rounding to even slightly biases even numbers, as it rounds `(.5,1.5)` to 1 but `[1.5,2.5]` to 2.

Comment: Convert.ToInt64(val * 100) is ~33% faster than Math.Round(val, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100

Comment: @JimBalter As zero is not rounded, rounding half up does introduce a positive bias, thus it is known as asymmetric rounding. The "round half to even" does not, if your distribution is even enough and the rounding doesn't bias either even or uneven numbers. See [half-way rounding tie-breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking).

Comment: The cutoff for "nearest" 32-bit signed integer is 14 zeros, 16 decimal places in `Convert.ToInt32(4.50000000000000044)` is converted to 4 `Convert.ToInt32(4.50000000000000045)` is converted to 5.  The final 4 and 5 in these conversion values goes on to infinity, I could not find how to place a bar over the last number with markup.

Comment: keep in mind this will not work if the double = `NaN`

Answer (score 40):

You can also use function:

```
//Works with negative numbers now
static int MyRound(double d) {
  if (d < 0) {
    return (int)(d - 0.5);
  }
  return (int)(d + 0.5);
}
```

Depending on the architecture it is several times faster.

Comment: This was perfect for me as Math.Round wasn't working the way I wanted it to.

Comment: @cullub yes it does. It converts the double d which had 0.5 appended to it, to an integer.

Comment: This is my preferred method - works in a very simple way. So much shorter, and easier to read than Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) and more concise than using an if statement to choose whether to round down or round up. AND, actually returns an integer at the end, not a double

Comment: See @Eternal21's comment below for odd behaviour on negative numbers (MyRound(-1.2)=0)

Comment: This worked better for me than Convert.ToInt32() since I'm not working with money. I want it to consistently round the same way regardless of even/odd numbers.

Answer (score 16):

```
double d;
int rounded = (int)Math.Round(d);
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old, but I came across it in my search for the answer to my similar question. I thought I would share the very useful tip that I have been given.

When converting to int, simply add `.5` to your value before downcasting. As downcasting to `int` always drops to the lower number (e.g. `(int)1.7 == 1`), if your number is `.5` or higher, adding `.5` will bring it up into the next number and your downcast to `int` should return the correct value. (e.g. `(int)(1.8 + .5) == 2`)

Comment: The problem is if you try to convert negative values that way.  For example -1.25 will end up equal to 0. (-1.25 + 0.5 = 0.75, and once cast down to int it's 0).  So you need to subtract 0.5 from negative values.

Comment: One can use `+ 0.5 * Math.Abs(d)`

Answer (score 1):

Methods in other answers throw `OverflowException` if the float value is outside the Int range. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Single_

```
int result = 0;
try {
    result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
catch (OverflowException) {
    if (value > 0) result = int.MaxValue;
    else result = int.Minvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Unity, use [Mathf.RoundToInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html).

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Prints 10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(10.0f));
        // Prints 10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(10.2f));
        // Prints 11
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(10.7f));
        // Prints 10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(10.5f));
        // Prints 12
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(11.5f));

        // Prints -10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(-10.0f));
        // Prints -10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(-10.2f));
        // Prints -11
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(-10.7f));
        // Prints -10
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(-10.5f));
        // Prints -12
        Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(-11.5f));
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/86ce57f70f76576207924c1757dca4d310fcfca7/Runtime/Export/Mathf.cs#L154)

```cs
public static int RoundToInt(float f) { return (int)Math.Round(f); }
```

Comment: Q does not mention or tag Unity.

Comment: @XenoRo I was answering this old question for those who searching for similar answers when using Unity.

Comment: You can answer your own questions for knowledge-sharing. Create a separate question specific to the API (in this case Unity) in cases like this. Answers should be approrpiate to the questions. Otherwise there could be an answer here for every single C# API with a rounding function.

Answer (score -1):

I'm developing a scientific calculator that sports an Int button.  I've found the following is a simple, reliable solution:

```
double dblInteger;
if( dblNumber < 0 )
   dblInteger = Math.Ceiling(dblNumber);
else
   dblInteger = Math.Floor(dblNumber);
```

Math.Round sometimes produces unexpected or undesirable results, and explicit conversion to integer (via cast or Convert.ToInt...) often produces wrong values for higher-precision numbers.  The above method seems to always work.

Comment: doesn't this round up all negative and round down all positive numbers? That's not necessarily the "neaerest" integer.

Comment: this is not the nearest number.

Comment: Given 1.99, this returns 1.0.

Comment: `Ceiling` is what we need to round up for positive numbers. Perfect! Upvoted.