# How could I convert data from string to long in c#

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, long-integer

How could i convert data from string to long in C#?

I have data

```
String strValue[i] ="1100.25";
```

now i want it in

```
long l1;
```

Comment: Longs represent integers. You've given a non-integer. What would you want to do with that?

Comment: What if strValue is "1100.75" ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633335/how-might-i-convert-a-double-to-the-nearest-integer-value

Comment: @magma: if you convert it into decimal then it will round off the number, i.e in this case if given number was 1100.75 then it will output 1101.

Comment: @charlie I was merely raising the issue, because MayP did not appear to be fully aware of the implication here. He might want to simply get rid of the non-integer part without any rounding, and that's fine, provided that it's really what he wants. Thank you though.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to get the integer part of that number you must first convert it to a floating number then cast to long.

```
long l1 = (long)Convert.ToDouble("1100.25");
```

You can use `Math` class to round up the number as you like, or just truncate...

- [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx)
- [Math.Ceil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)

Comment: This is going to give you `FormatException` if you run this on the specified input.

Comment: @zespri, no, at least not in most cultures... But it would indeed fail in cultures where the decimal separator is not "."

Comment: using your code, this value 2037104000005652013   changed to 2037104000005651968. ?

Comment: You need to specify an explicit culture that treats `.` as a decimal separator (`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` would work).

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan The biggest integer that can be safely represented in a `double` is `2^53`, and yours is bigger than that, so when converted to a long you'll get some funky results.

Answer (score 59):

You can also use `long.TryParse` and `long.Parse`.

```
long l1;
l1 = long.Parse("1100.25");
//or
long.TryParse("1100.25", out l1);
```

Answer (score 22):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx

`l1 = Convert.ToInt64(strValue)`

Though the example you gave isn't an integer, so I'm not sure why you want it as a long.

Answer (score 15):

```
long l1 = Convert.ToInt64(strValue);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Not recomended when used with linq. It gives me an exception.    long.Parse("1100.25")    works for me

Answer (score 7):

You won't be able to convert it directly to long because of the decimal point i think you should convert it into decimal and then convert it into long something like this:

```
String strValue[i] = "1100.25";
long l1 = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(strValue));
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

long is internally represented as System.Int64 which is a 64-bit signed integer.
The value you have taken "1100.25" is actually decimal and not integer hence it can not be converted to long.

You can use:

```
String strValue = "1100.25";
decimal lValue = Convert.ToDecimal(strValue);
```

to convert it to decimal value

Answer (score 1):

You can also do using `Int64.TryParse` Method. It will return '0' if their is any string value but did not generate an error.

```
Int64 l1;

Int64.TryParse(strValue, out l1);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own conversion function:

```
    static long ToLong(string lNumber)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lNumber))
            throw new Exception("Not a number!");
        char[] chars = lNumber.ToCharArray();
        long result = 0;
        bool isNegative = lNumber[0] == '-';
        if (isNegative && lNumber.Length == 1)
            throw new Exception("- Is not a number!");

        for (int i = (isNegative ? 1:0); i < lNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(chars[i]))
            {
                if (chars[i] == '.' && i < lNumber.Length - 1 && Char.IsDigit(chars[i+1]))
                {
                    var firstDigit = chars[i + 1] - 48;
                    return (isNegative ? -1L:1L) * (result + ((firstDigit < 5) ? 0L : 1L));    
                }
                throw new InvalidCastException($" {lNumber} is not a valid number!");
            }
            result = result * 10 + ((long)chars[i] - 48L);
        }
        return (isNegative ? -1L:1L) * result;
    }
```

It can be improved further:

- performance wise
- make the validation stricter in the sense that it currently doesn't care if characters after first decimal aren't digits
- specify rounding behavior as parameter for conversion function. it currently does rounding