# Convert 0x0000000000000001 from string to long

Tags: c#, string, long-integer

I have a csv file that stores long values in this format:

```
0x0000000000000001
0x0000000000000002
0x0000000000000020
0x0000000000040000
```

I want to save the values in long variables.
I can save the data directly as long for example:

```
long t = 0x0000000000040000;
```

This does not throw an exception.

However, I can't seem to convert this format from string (as i read it from the csv file) to long.

I tried

```
Convert.ToInt64("0x0000000000040000");
```

as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330306/how-could-i-convert-data-from-string-to-long-in-c-sharp)

I also tried

```
long.Parse("0x0000000000040000", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

But this throws also an exception

I can parse it when I get rid of the 0x at the front.
But the number is then saved without the zeros (e.g. 0x0000000000000001 becomes just 1), which is not what I want.

Tl;dr:

Does anyone know how to parse

```
string s = "0x0000000000000001";
```

to

```
long l = 0x0000000000000001;
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse hex values into a uint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/how-to-parse-hex-values-into-a-uint)

Comment: use `s.Subtring(2)`, thus you remove the first two characters `0x`

Comment: »But the number is then saved without the zeros (e.g. 0x0000000000000001 becomes just 1), which is not what I want.« -- The number is the same. If you want to *format* it differently when writing it somewhere (e.g. `l.ToString("x16")`), that's another point, but you shouldn't usually care about how a number is represented when it makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Joey you are totally right. Now I feel stupid...

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279892/convert-a-string-containing-a-hexadecimal-value-starting-with-0x-to-an-integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
   String source = "0x0000000000040000";

   long result = Convert.ToInt64("0" + source.TrimStart('0', 'x'), 16);
```

or even

```
   long result = Convert.ToInt64(source, 16);
```

To convert back to `string`:

```
   String back = String.Format("0x{0:x16}", result);
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64(source.TrimStart('0', 'x'), 16)` is problematic with `"0x0000000000000000"`. Edited: Removed wrong statement from comment, sorry.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: you're quite right: `0x0` is a *counter example*, I've edited the answer: `"0" +  source.TrimStart('0', 'x')`

Comment: @Dimitry Good answer, but the trimming part is completely pointless, `Convert.ToInt64` handles the `0x` hex prefix just fine.

Comment: Interesting, on my machine (.NET vers. 4.5.2), `Convert.ToInt64(null, 16)` succeeds and gives zero, while `Convert.ToInt64("", 16)` blows up with a "wrong" exception (expected `FormatException` but got `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (from a deeper point in the call stack)). *Edit:* Hmm, I note that this behavior is documented. Still surprising to me.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is that you could simply omit the first two characters for your conversion by using `Substring` method:

```
string s = "0x0000000000040000";
long l = Convert.ToInt64(s.Substring(2), 16);
```

Comment: Counter example: `s = "0x00000FFFF"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I was surprised that you are actually... right! But I wonder why...

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64(s.Substring(2), 16);`, please, note *16*

Answer (score 0):

This code converts hex to int and checks for invalid inputs plus parses 0x while handling 0x00 too

```
if (int.TryParse(stringname.TrimStart('0').TrimStart('x'), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int result))
{
    //use the value of "result"
}
else
{
    //check the input
}
```

You need to add

```
using System.Globalization;
```