# C# Memory.WriteFloat() Cannot convert string to long

Tags: c#, memory

The line of code with the issue:

```
memory.WriteFloat(tp_x, this.X)
```

this.X is fine and works with no issues.
For the value tp_x, it is a STRING.
I am taking this from a text file and parsing it to an exact value. I have tried several times to convert this string to Int32/64, float, long, etc. But the memory.WriteFloat() is not taking it without an error.
[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yItbk.png)

I have tried to use

```
memory.ReadFloat(tp_X)
```

But I get the same error.
Cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'. I have tried so much different codes to convert it and use it, but nothing has worked or changed so I am asking a question here. I wouldn't be asking if I had no idea. Thank you, please let me know!

***EDITED for pm100***
Here is my new code:
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G97Cz.png)
[Where I get my error Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwTlh.png)
So using your code @pm100 as seen in the pictures, I get no problems and I can compile perfectly. Although, when I execute this I get error

I get the error System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
at System.Number.ParseInt64(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Int64.Parse(String s)

My code:
int counter = 0;
// location is the selected index of the combobox that the user selected

```
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"path"))
                {
                    if (counter == location)
                    {
                        string[] words = line.Split(",");
                        int tempcounter = 1;
                        string tp_x = "";
                        string tp_y = "";
                        string tp_z = "";
                        foreach (var word in words)
                        {
                            if (tempcounter == 1)
                            {
                                tp_x += word;
                            }
                            if (tempcounter == 2)
                            {
                                tp_y += word;
                            }
                            if (tempcounter == 3)
                            {
                                tp_z += word;
                            }
                            tempcounter += 1;
 //everytime works perfect above, now below 
                            long l = System.Int64.Parse(tp_x);
                            long l2 = System.Int64.Parse(tp_y);
                            long l3 = System.Int64.Parse(tp_z);
                            tp_xx = l;
                            tp_yy = l2;
                            tp_zz = l3;


                            for (int i = 0; i < address.vz.Length; i++)
                            {
                                mem.WriteFloat(tp_xx, this.X);
                                mem.WriteFloat(tp_yy, this.Y);
                                mem.WriteFloat(tp_zz, this.Z);
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    counter += 1;
                }
```

Comment: “tp_x, it is a `string`”; so convert it to a `long`, or as a search phrase “C# how to convert string to long”.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330306 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number , https://blog.elmah.io/csharp-how-to-convert-a-string-to-int/  etc.

Comment: Perhaps tp_x should be a `long` already (ie. `long tp_x;`), with any conversions occurring before it is assigned. Then the value of tp_x would not need to be converted as the usage sites.

Comment: @user2864740 Tried that several times. I tried so many different things online to convert etc. No luck! :)

Comment: @newcaharpercoder Then the trying was incorrectly applied. It’s not practical to attempt to provide more input, given a lack of a clear minimal reproduction example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user2864740 I did mention at the bottom. :)

Comment: And also, long tp_x; won't work etc. As I am reading from a text file, so I will have to use string and when I do long tp_x; I will get cannot convert str to long error.

Comment: `long tp_x` *will* work, when following through with the *full* suggestion of “with any conversions occurring before it is assigned”. So, when reading in text as a string, **convert the read `string` to a long, and assign that value to the `long tp_x` variable**. Then `tp_x` (now a `long`) can be used as shown, as it is already the correct type. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number for methods of conversion. In the MSDN code, `string input` and `string stringInput`, eg, represents the text value read.

Comment: Copy the console texts and paste here, not in images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: @newcsharpcoder you didn't show your new code **in texts**. Never put code in comments, no one will read that

Comment: @phuclv Apologies. I edited my message with pastebin if that's ok.

Comment: @newcsharpcoder no that's not allowed because external links can be rotten at any time, rendering the question invalid. Please see [ask], [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/230282). Also read [tour] to see how this site works. It's not a Q&A website as one might think. And as I said, **never post code in comments**. Edit everything inside the question itself. You need to create a [mcve] as  
user2864740 said

Comment: Sorry. I added to message

Comment: this message is saying that the string doesnt contain a number. Pause in the debugger and examine the value you are passing to the parse function

Answer (score 1):

You need Int64.Parse

```
     string s="1234";
    long l = System.Int64.Parse(s);
```

Or if you are not sure that the string contains a valid number use

```
bool success = Int64.TryParse(s, out long l);
```

Comment: Or just `long.Parse`/`long.TryParse`. Whichever you prefer, really.

Comment: @pm100 I got the error ************** Exception Text **************
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int64.Parse(String s)

Comment: @pm100 Using the code bool success = Int64.TryParse(s, out long l); works iwith no errors. But doesn't update the value for when I change memory.WriteFloat

Comment: post the code that you have thats calling tryparse (edit the question)

Comment: @newcsharpcoder Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse) can save a lot of time.. while TryParse did not throw an exception, it did not “work” to convert the non-parseable string value. The result will be `false` and the `out` value will be set to 0 if the conversion fails: “The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or Empty, is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue.”

Comment: @user2864740 Tried to use that. But got the error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'long'. Code: mem.WriteFloat(TryToParse("25.3"), this.X); Also. I read the docs

Comment: @pm100 Sorry, now I edited my message with your code and the error etc. Thank you