# Rounding troubles

Tags: c#

I have this problem: I need to do the following rounding

```
4.2 --> 5
4.6 --> 5
4.0 --> 4
```

How could I achieve this?

edit: I miswrote the 4.0 rounding, I'm going to use this to create a 2d array in which I'll store the chars of a sentence. To perform this one dimension is a variable a, and the other is the length of the sentence divided by a

Comment: What does the comma mean?  Is that a decimal point?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I'm going to edit it right now

Comment: Why would four round to zero? What's the logic you need, in words?

Comment: In some cultures, comma separates the faction and whole number part.

Comment: There is no rounding function that could do the 3 roundings

Comment: @PhilBolduc Thanks I realise that, but I was not sure that that was the meaning the OP wishes to use

Comment: Originally I misread and thought it said 4.0->4, in which case Ceiling would do the trick. But I can't come up with any logical reason to make four round to zero. What about 3.2, 2.6 and 1? What would those do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I convert a double to the nearest integer value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633335/how-might-i-convert-a-double-to-the-nearest-integer-value)

Comment: @3vts zero is not the closest integer to four. Question needs clarification

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 seems I was right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two, the ceiling function is what you want (`Math.Ceiling` for C#). I am not however aware of any function related to rounding that would map 4.0 to 0.

Clarification: rounding, flooring, and ceiling an integer will result in the same integer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on question edits, it is just Math.Ceiling(value)

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tbaa3m)

Comment: I guess you could also do `value % 1 == 0` instead of using `value - Mathf.Floor(value) == 0`.