# Double Percentage round up

Tags: c#, double, percentage

hey guys can you help me i will round up the double like this
1.double a = 0,68777777 -> to a textbox.text = 69%
2.double b = 0,54333333 -> to a textbox.text = 54%
but how ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `textbox.text = $"{percent * 100:f0}%";` where  `percent = 0.68777777;` or `0.5433333333`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are solely looking for the text then you should look into [`double.ToString(string? format)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-6.0#System_Double_ToString_System_String_).

Precisely, you're looking for the "P0" format.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`Math.Round()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0), it is surcharged to be able to round `double` values to `int` values. Then you'll have to display the `int` value in your textbox

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633335/how-might-i-convert-a-double-to-the-nearest-integer-value) to see some examples

Comment: You might also want to address that the values are currently expressed between `0` and `1`.

Comment: I also highly recommend providing links to the _English_ documentation, since that's the language of StackOverflow. I did this for you by replacing the `fr-fr` in the URL with `en-us`.